# Convert uintptr_t to id<MTLTexture>

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, metal

I wanted to create simple iOS plugin which can draw the texture to unity Texture2D. I've done it by CreateExternalTexture() and UpdateExternalTexture(), it's working fine, but I'm curious if I can actually fill the Unity texture straight from iOS side. Here's my code of iOS plugin:

```
//
//  testTexturePlugin.m
//  Unity-iPhone
//
//  Created by user on 18/01/16.
//
//

#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#include "UnityMetalSupport.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static UIImage* LoadImage()
{
    NSString* imageName = @"logo"; //[NSString stringWithUTF8String: filename];
    NSString* imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: imageName ofType: @"png"];

    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
}

// you need to free this pointer
static void* LoadDataFromImage(UIImage* image)
{
    CGImageRef imageData    = image.CGImage;
    unsigned   imageW       = CGImageGetWidth(imageData);
    unsigned   imageH       = CGImageGetHeight(imageData);

    // for the sake of the sample we enforce 128x128 textures
    //assert(imageW == 128 && imageH == 128);

    void* textureData = ::malloc(imageW * imageH * 4);
    ::memset(textureData, 0x00, imageW * imageH * 4);

    CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, imageW, imageH, 8, imageW * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageData), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(textureContext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageW, imageH), imageData);
    CGContextRelease(textureContext);

    return textureData;
}

static void CreateMetalTexture(uintptr_t texRef, void* data, unsigned w, unsigned h)
{
#if defined(__IPHONE_8_0) && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

    NSLog(@"texRef iOS = %lu", texRef);

    id<MTLTexture> tex = (id<MTLTexture>)(size_t)texRef;

    MTLRegion r = MTLRegionMake3D(0, 0, 0, w, h, 1);
    [tex replaceRegion: r mipmapLevel: 0 withBytes: data bytesPerRow: w * 4];

#else

#endif
}

extern "C" void FillUnityTexture(uintptr_t texRef)
{
    UIImage*    image       = LoadImage();
    void*       textureData = LoadDataFromImage(image);

    if (UnitySelectedRenderingAPI() == apiMetal)
        CreateMetalTexture(texRef, textureData, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    ::free(textureData);
}
```

And here's the Unity code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class TextureHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private Renderer _mesh;

    private Texture2D _meshTexture;

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void FillUnityTexture(IntPtr texRef);

    void Start () {

        _meshTexture = new Texture2D(200, 200, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        _mesh.material.SetTextureScale ("_MainTex", new Vector2 (-1, -1));
        _mesh.material.mainTexture = _meshTexture;

        IntPtr texPtr = _meshTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr();
        Debug.Log("texPtr Unity = " + texPtr);

        FillUnityTexture(texPtr);
    }
}
```

Pointer on the Unity texture is passing to the iOS plugin correctly, I checked. But I have the crash in this line on iOS plugin:

```
[tex replaceRegion: r mipmapLevel: 0 withBytes: data bytesPerRow: w * 4];
```

and I'm pretty sure that I have this problem because of wrong converting of the pointer on Unity texture (uintptr_t) to metal texture (id).

So my question is - how can I convert pointer to the texture to MTLTexture properly?

Comment: Although it's not pretty, that cast should work, as `GetNativeTexturePtr` returns an `id<MTLTexture>`. It does seem that your code could write outside the bounds of the texture if the dimensions of the image you load exceed the dimensions of the texture (200x200). Have you verified that this isn't the case?

Comment: Your guess was correct :) But still there's no any picture on unity texture,just purple color. Can it be because I'm trying to upload image which resolution is much biiger than 200x200?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should read about ARC.

You can use `__bridge_retained` to transfer the ownership of newly created `id<MTLTexture>` object to `uintptr_t` code. When you want to convert the `uintptr_t` back to `id<MTLTexture>` use `__bridge` if you don't want to transfer the ownership back or use `__bridge_transfer` when you do.