# Send id<MTLTexture> from ios to unity

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a plugin for unity, and I need to send a texture from ios to unity.
There is a `UnitySendMessage` function which takes `char*` as a parameter, but I didn't find a way to convert `id<MTLTexture>` to `char*`.

How can I send `id<MTLTexture>` from ios and receive it in unity?

My current code :

```
//ios side ...
id<MTLTexture> _texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture);
UnitySendMessage(CALLBACK_OBJECT, CALLBACK_TEXTURE_READY,_texture);//error
//...

//unity side
private void OnTextureReady(string texture_str)
{
   IntPtr texture = new IntPtr(Int32.Parse(texture_str));
   int width = 256;
   int height = 256;
   rawImage.texture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(width, height, 
   TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false, texture);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iOS plugin documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) says that you can only pass strings using UnitySendMessage.

The workaround would be to create a mapping from string to texture objects in Objective-C side, pass the string key via UnitySendMessage and then retrieve the texture object using a custom DllImport function.

Declare you map:

```
// class field
{
    NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, id<MTLTexture>> _textures;
}

// in constructor
_textures = [NSMutableDictionary new];

// in function code
NSString *textureName = @"cookies";
_textures[textureName] = texture; // save MTLTexture for later

UnitySendMessage(CALLBACK_OBJECT, CALLBACK_TEXTURE_READY, textureName);
```

On the C# side CreateExternalTexture requires a pointer to a texture object of type `IntPtr`. To obtain it you can declare a DllImport function that takes a texture name and returns `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
static extern IntPtr GetMetalTexturePointerByName(string textureName);
```

and implement it on the iOS side like so:

```
return plugin->_textures[textureName];
```

Not sure if it works though in terms of what `CreateExternalTexture` expects.

See also this post, a guy is doing something similar (but reverse):
[Convert uintptr_t to id<MTLTexture>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854854/convert-uintptr-t-to-idmtltexture)